# How to show an alert when duplicate values are entered to a primary key field

Tags: vb.net

I have already created a MS Access DB and connect it to my VB.NET application.

Now, I need a `message box` that will prompt me when I enter the same SerialID which is a primary key. Message should inform that *Serial already exists, choose another one.*

I'm using the function `ReqBindingSource.AddNew()`

please help me.

Comment: If the serial is a primary key,DB itself will prompt you and insertion will fail. You just have to catch the error if any and pop up your message box.

Comment: Why do you want to insert a value into a primary key column? Use identity fields or sequence to generate a new ID everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Query the database for the value entered and if you get a result then you display the message.
2. Try to insert the data and catch the exception that is thrown on a duplicate primary key and then display your message.

Comment: It's the same way as you catch any exception.